# Statistical test for Percent Correct?

Tags: statistical-significance

I have 3 subjects. Each subject completed the same experiment with 4 randomly interspersed stimulus types. For each stimulus type the subject completed 120 trials on a 2AFC (2-alternative forced choice) task. From these I can calculate a percent correct.

I would like to know if the overall percent correct is statistically different between the four stimulus types, but I am not sure what statistical test to do or how to combine the three subjects.

I am wondering if I need to do something with d' or t-tests?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the Pearson Chi-squared test. It generalizes a two-sample t test to more than two samples.

There are a number of good presentations on the Internet. Here are two with particularly clear and non-overly-technical explanations for applied work:

http://math.hws.edu/javamath/ryan/ChiSquare.html
http://courses.washington.edu/dphs568/course/day12.htm